# Recommended way to use StringTranslationTrait in PHP8 enums

Tags: 10

PHP8 has that new cool "enum" feature that should replace all class constants and would make coding easier and safer. One problem I encoutered is that many common Drupal traits (foremost the translation trait) have properties and therefore can not be used in enums.

So what I would like to do is

```
<?php

use Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\StringTranslationTrait;
use Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\TranslatableMarkup;

enum Season: string {

  // Can't use this because that trait has a property 
  // and enums can only use traits without properties.
  use StringTranslationTrait;

  case SUMMER = 'summer';
  case WINTER = 'winter';

  public function getLabel(): TranslatableMarkup {
    return match ($this) {
      Season::SUMMER => $this->t('summer'), // can't use OOP here :(
      Season::WINTER => $this->t('winter'),
    };
  }
}
```

I know that I can still use old-school procedural code

```
    return match ($this) {
      Season::SUMMER => t('summer'), // that's what we did 20 years ago
      Season::WINTER => t('winter'),
    };
```

but is there a "more beautiful" way? I'm on a D10/PHP8 project , procedural code is dicouraged, but traits with properties are very common in the Drupal ecosystem. Especially getting a translatable label of a constant is a very common use-case.

What is the recommended way of using/injecting Drupal traits (especially the StringTranslationTrait) into enums?

Comment: Instead of calling `t()`, create the `TranslatableMarkup` instance as `t()` does. Since enumerations cannot have properties, that is the only way I think possible.

Comment: You didn't use `match` in PHP twenty years ago... 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up on apaderno's comment, rather than using the Drupal API to create a `TranslatableMarkup` instance, you can instantiate the class yourself.

```php
use Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\TranslatableMarkup;

enum Season: string {

  case SUMMER = 'summer';
  case WINTER = 'winter';

  public function getLabel(): TranslatableMarkup {
    return match ($this) {
      Season::SUMMER => new TranslatableMarkup('summer'),
      Season::WINTER => new TranslatableMarkup('winter'),
    };
  }
}
```